# RecyclerView with GridLayoutManager and reverse layout stack to bottom

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, gridlayoutmanager

I am using a `RecyclerView` with a `GridLayoutManager`. On that layout manager, I call `setReverseLayout(true)` so the elements are displayed in reverse order.

But now, the `RecyclerView` is initially displayed from the end of the list. I know there is a `setStackFromEnd(boolean)` method, but it is not compatible with `GridLayoutManager`.

What is the best way to display the elements in reverse order and still having the `RecyclerView` being displayed from the top?

Here is my layout file using the `RecyclerView`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.mgaetan89.showsrage.fragment.ShowsSectionFragment">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/grid_margin"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/fab_spacing"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@android:id/empty"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/no_shows"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/add_show"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end|right"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add_black_24dp"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: retrieving the item at `getCount() - position - 1`?

Comment: @MrsEd I added my layout to my original post.
@Blackbelt That could work. But isn't that putting some `LayoutManager` logic inside the `Adapter`?

Comment: I end up using @Blackbelt solution, even if I think there is a bette way to do it.

Comment: if you find one, don't forget to share it

Comment: If you are populating the grid from ArrayList you can just reverse it with Collections.reverse(array);

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @DeepLathia for your answer.

Use the below code.

```
Collections.reverse(yourList); // add your ArrayList
```

Don't do anything with `GridLayoutManager` because GridLayoutManager not support `stackFromEnd(true)`.

I hope it is helpful.

Answer (score -1):

I tired got to find solution with recycler view so finally I used GridView

```
<GridView
    android:id="@+id/lv_explore"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:dividerHeight="0dip"
    android:horizontalSpacing="5dp"
    android:numColumns="3"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:verticalSpacing="5dp"
    android:stackFromBottom="true" />
```

and used this property `android:stackFromBottom="true"`